# Django website settings variables

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I’m Django beginner, I would like to know some best practices for saving variables about website like: email, website title, url, meta description, google analytics id.

I want to edit those variables inside admin and also print inside templates.

Should i create special app for that?

Thanks

Comment: If you want it to be editable in the django-admin, then yes, you might aswell create an app called `app_settings` and store it in the database (in models.py). However, the best practice is to put them in the settings.py file, so that someone with admin access does not accidentally change the values.

Answer (score 0):

I place meta tags and website title etc. in the `head` tags of my `base.html` template. I'm new as well but this is how I learned to do it.